# How do I find the definition of a Power BI Data Selected Event

Tags: javascript, powerbi-embedded

I am using Power BI embedded in an AngularJS application (yes, I know that it is old).  I am using the following to trigger an event:

```
      report.on("dataSelected", function (event) {
        console.log(scope.renderedReport);
        console.log(event.detail);
      });
```

I can see the various structures of the "detail" object.  However, I am having a hard time finding anywhere that really shows what all of the sub-objects should look like.  I need to persist this information to a Database and I am trying to build the C# objects for the detail object and subsequently the SQL Tables as well.  If anyone can point me in the direction of where this event.detail object is defined at, I'd be appreciative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According the [official wiki](https://github.com/microsoft/PowerBI-JavaScript/wiki/Handling-Events), it is:

```
dataSelected
    report: Report
    page: Page
    visual: IVisual
    filters: IFilter[]
    dataPoints: (Array of data points)
    each point has:
        1) **identity** array
        2) **values** array
```

You may want to check this demo too

https://microsoft.github.io/PowerBI-JavaScript/demo/dataselection.html

[image]